# Linear interpolation in griddata

Tags: matlab, interpolation

I want to know how [`griddata`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/griddata.html) uses linear interpolation.

Does it just consider like four neighbor points of the point where we want to find the value or uses the whole convex hull?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs for griddata will guide you in this. Essentially, it does a delaunay triangulation of your point set, then for any new point, determine which simplex the point falls in. Interpolation within a simplex is linear. Thus in 2 dimensions, three points define a triangle, and 3 points determine a locally planar model for z(x,y).